# Where do I report an iproute2 bug?

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I have a command in shell script:

```
ip neigh flush dev eth0 192.168.1.21
```

which cause messages (syslog) to record the following error:

```
Feb  2 15:53:03 rpiautomation kernel: [1324706.360319] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes in process `ip'.
```

My Raspberry runs Jessie, updated and upgraded.
The version of ip is:

```
ip utility, iproute2-ss140804
```

I assume a bug exists, and wonder where can I report it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Iproute](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) is specific to linux based systems and I believe developed in tandem with the kernel.  In any case, it's a handled on a kernel mailing list, [netdev](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#netdev), although whether or not they welcome bug reports there I don't know ([see also here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netdev-FAQ.txt)).

You could instead start downstream with [Debian](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/); I think starting with Raspbian would be a waste of time unless it turns out to be non-reproducible on Debian.